# How to centralize setup of testdata to be shared across multiple testmethods

Tags: apex, trigger, test-setup

I'm quite tired so I don't know if the title makes sense, but basically I have written a test with two test methods. However in these methods I have to create and insert the Lead set-up first which is this:

```
// Set up the new lead
    Lead newLead = new Lead();
    newLead.Title = 'Mr';
    newLead.AnnualRevenue = 18000;
    newLead.City = 'Sutton';
    newLead.Street = 'Street';
    newLead.Country = 'United Kingdom';
    newLead.Description = 'A test description';
    newLead.Company = 'blah';
    newLead.Email = 'test@test.org';
    newLead.Fax = '111222333';
    newLead.FirstName = 'John';
    newLead.LastName = 'Parker';
    newLead.Industry = 'Smith';
    newLead.MobilePhone = '07999888777';
    newLead.NumberOfEmployees = 4;
    newLead.NumberofLocations__c = 2;
    newLead.Phone = '07111222333';
    newLead.PostalCode = 'Post Code';
    newLead.Rating = 'Hot';
    newLead.Website = 'www.lead.com';
// Don't forget to insert the newLead object;
    insert newLead;
```

I have to write this out twice, however I feel this is un-professional(due to being told at work to not repeat myself and use partials) and I want to know if there is a way to define this once in the test class, then call to reference it so I don't have to keep repeating myself. Is there a way to do this or do I have to define the new Lead object every time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take help from `testmethod`. Use test setup methods (methods that are annotated with @testSetup) to create test records once and then access them in any test method in the test class. Test setup methods are useful and can be time-saving when you need to create a common set of records that all test methods operate on or prerequisite data.

[Reference:](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses)